# Ruby on Rails - On click event to "link_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The goal here is that once a user clicks on a "link_to" button, that a ruby method will execute but I am unclear as to how I am to do that.

Here is my link to call within my .html.erb file:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@artist.related_artists[1], class: 'artist_show_related'), artist_path(@artist.related_artists[0]) %>
```

Is there are way to cause this to also run a ruby method once clicked?

Comment: `@artist.related_artists[1]` what does this return ?

Comment: `link_to` takes a path defined in your `routes.rb` which executes a method/action defined in corresponding controller's public scope.